# Insert data using serializer class django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, one-to-one

I am a beginner with Django and especially with the Django REST framework.
Inside "UserRegistration" class, I want to create a new user and ExtendUser using "UserSerializer". how can I do that?

## this is my models.py

```
class ExtendUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='userImages/', default="default.webp", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

## this is my serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, style={'input_type':'password'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'password', 'password2']
        extra_kwargs = {'password' : {'write_only':True,}}

        
    def save(self):
        name = self.validated_data['first_name']
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        if len(password) < 8:
             raise serializers.ValidationError({'error':'Password must be 8-16 Characters '+
                'and contain both numbers and letters/special character.'})
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'Password':'Password and Confirm Password Should be Same!'})
        email = self.validated_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists() == True:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'E-mail': f"{email} this email already been used. Try another email."})

        user = User.objects.create_user(username=email, email=email, password=password, first_name=name)
        return user


class ExtendUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ExtendUser
        fields = '__all__'
```

## this is my views.py

```
class UserRegistration(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        user = UserSerializer(data=self.request.data)
        if user.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user.save()
            refreshToken = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            context = {'access': str(refreshToken.access_token),
                    'refresh': str(refreshToken)}
            return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            
        return Response(user.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case:

```
class ExtendUser(User):
    ...
```

and:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ExtendUser
```

Django made o2o-foreign self.

But it is not really correct, it is better to override default User Model
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

Answer (score 1):

```
class ExtendUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, style= 
      {'input_type':'password'})
    password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, style= 
      {'input_type':'password'})
    email = serialzier.CharField()
    first_name = serialzier.CharField()


    class Meta:
      model = ExtendUser
      fields = ['email','password1','password2','first_name','address','phone','picture']
```

Your Views,py

Firstly we create user and proceed to extend user

```
class UserRegistration(CreateAPIView):

  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    data = serialzier.validated_data
    password_1 = data.pop('password1')
    password_2 = data.pop('password2')
    email = data.pop('email')
    first_name = data.pop('first_name')
    user = User.objects.create(email = email,first_name = first_name)
    user.set_password(password_1)
    user.save()
    ExtendUser.objects.create(user=user,**data)
        refreshToken = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        context = {'access': str(refreshToken.access_token),
                'refresh': str(refreshToken)}
        return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        
    return Response(user.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

You can do further validation with Validate Function Please have try once if this solution works

please let me know if you got any error